# How to use a Django validator to limit dates to 1900 or greater

Tags: python, django

I found [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/e15567bf58) showing the `_datere` pattern now requires a date > 1900 but ... when I look into `django.core.validators` today I don't see anything like this (the commit linked to above does say it's from 7 years ago).

What happened to this validation in django and what are people using today in Django 1.4.1 to get this type of validation?

I'm asking this because of the strftime error:

```
"ValueError('year=1800 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900',)"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@SimeonVisser gave a great explanation of the reason you used to get this exception and why you no longer do.

If still want dates greater than 1900 as business logic and not as an actual inherent limitation, you should be able to use the built-in Django `MinValueValidator`. Just feed it a date/datetime of 1900-01-01, i.e.

```
validators=[MinValueValidator(datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0))]
```

Comment: I like this approach for a simple one off but I think long term I'll end up creating a custom field that applies this same logic such that it could be reused across my django app. In reality I should write this once and submit a pull request to have it in the django project (I can't be the only person having to hand-roll this)

Answer (score 3):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/df2b19cc17) there is a new module `django.utils.datetime_safe` which supports dates with year < 1900.

You can use `strftime` from that module if you wish to support dates with year < 1900. Similarly, you can use `new_datetime` (`new_date`) to obtain a `datetime` (`date`) that supports years < 1900:

```
value = datetime_safe.new_datetime(value)
# or:
value = datetime_safe.new_date(value)
```

The other alternative is to write a custom validator yourself for forms and enforce that the year is no less than 1900.

Comment: I'd like to reuse a django validator honestly ... hate to write code when I know someone else already done the work :D

Comment: I'm looking for something that will throw an exception when the value given is < 1900. The above doesn't seem to care -it just returns the value either way ... (can you clarify)

Comment: The above code prevents the error that you get with `strftime` (as limiting dates to >= 1900 is only a workaround, unless that is really what you want). So you are right that it does not throw an exception, it allows you to use dates < 1900. If you want an exception then you need to write a validator (I'm not sure if Django 1.4 has such a validator as the "year 1900" was only a limitation, not a necessary feature).